# turtle library isn't working in my pycharm . every time i write a code its throwing a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import *

color('black', 'pink')
title('art')
speed(5)
bgcolor("black")
r, g, b = 200, 0, 0


def flwr():
    for i in range(300):
        begin_fill()
        circle(190 - i, 90)
        left(90)
        circle(190 - i, 90)
        left(18)


flwr()
mainloop()
```

this is the error i get everytime[![[image]]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonprog\01.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 1293
    TurtleScreen._RUNNING True       raise terminater
                          ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

can someone help me fix this problem! let me know if i have done something wrong
as far as my code concern i don't think there's anything wrong.
i'm getting error from turtle.py don't know why

Comment: Code works for me. Did you change `turtle.py` at all? That is the library and should not be messed with. Restore it to its [original version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de33df27aaf930be6a34027c530a651f0b4c91f5/Lib/turtle.py#L1293), looks like `TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True`. It's a good idea to state your version of CPython. `from turtle import *` is poor practice because it floods the namespace--use `import turtle` only. See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a problem witht he define part, cause this is happening me too and it worked fine until I added define

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).